# How can I disable weekends in q-date using moment business days

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, momentjs, quasar

I'm using quasar's q-date component in my project. I want to disable weekends and past days while using it. I use the momenten business day library for this, but the moment return an object and q-date cannot detect it. how do you think i can solve this problem

HTML(lang=>pug)

```
q-date(v-model="userInfo.date" mask="YYYY-MM-DD" :options="getAvailableDate" first-day-of-week="1")
```

SCRIPT

```
  getAvailableDate(d) {
      const day = moment(d).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
      console.log(moment(day, 'DD/MM/YYYY').monthBusinessDays())
      return moment(day, 'DD/MM/YYYY').monthBusinessDays() && d >= date.formatDate(Date.now(), 'YYYY/MM/DD')
      
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try passing the date to the function:
`:options="getAvailableDate(userInfo.date)"`

You could test by just returning true or false to check if there is an issue elswhere.

More info on use of v-bind:
[Vue doumentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#using-javascript-expressions)
[Simple explanation](https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/9a7vft/question_is_it_considered_bad_practice_to_vbind/e4tef8h/)

Answer (score 0):

Using options you disable weekend days using the following function:
In the script:
import moment from 'moment';

```
  const datesFn = (date: string) => {
    const dayOfWeek = moment(date, 'YYYY/MM/DD').day();

    return dayOfWeek !== 0 && dayOfWeek !== 6;
  };
```

In the template:

```
<q-input :options="datesFn" />
```